# Fixing IllegalStateException

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, illegalstateexception

```
try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        getStockInfoFromJSON(response.body().string());
    } catch (IOException | JSONException | IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.i("GraphAsyncTask", e.toString());
    }
```

For the code block seen above, I am now getting an IllegalStateException. I wasn't getting this error originally. I needed to change the API, so the URL in the request object is different. The error comes after the Response object is created. The getStockInfoFromJSON() method isn't running. I know it isn't running because I placed a log statement at the very beginning and it didn't show up in the console. How can I keep this error from being thrown.

```
private void getStockInfoFromJSON(String JsonString)
        throws JSONException {
    Log.i("MSA JSON string", JsonString);
    MyStocksActivity.StockData = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject Json = new JSONObject(JsonString);
    JSONObject StockInfo = Json.getJSONObject("Time Series (Daily)");
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    StockInfo.toJSONArray(array);
    Log.i("MSA", "JSON array " + StockInfo.toString());

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        StockData datum = new StockData();
        JSONObject stockPrice = array.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.i("stock price array", stockPrice.toString());
        String date = array.getString(i);
        Log.i("date", date);
        String[] stringDate = date.split("-");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Integer.parseInt(stringDate[0]),
                Integer.parseInt(stringDate[1]), Integer.parseInt(stringDate[2].substring(0, 2)));
        Log.i("cal", cal.toString());
        datum.date = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        datum.price = array.getDouble(3);
        datum.CalDate = date.split(" ")[0];
        MyStocksActivity.StockData.add(datum);

    }
}
```

This is the error message I get.

```
07-03 15:05:29.586 27929-28167/com.example.sam_chordas.stockhawk I/GraphAsyncTask: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Also it'll tell you what caused the Exception in the console output (posting it here will help us too)

Comment: @billynomates no line was given in the console

Comment: @billynomates i just removed the illegalstateexception from the catch block. the console points to the getStockInfroFromJson() method when its called in the try block

Comment: Are you reading the response body twice? You can only call string() once.

Comment: @billynomates string() is only called once

Comment: @billynomates just realized I called string again in a log statement...nvmd, thx

Comment: Haha it's ok. If I post my comment as an answer can you accept it please? :)

Comment: Instead of **Log.i("GraphAsyncTask", e.toString());** write **e.printStackTrace();** then post the logs here

Comment: Please note: You do not need an Asynctask with Okhttp or Retrofit. You instead enqueue a call, not directly execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you reading the response body twice? You can only call `string()` once.